# Any way to get actual free changes on TAP?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, cancellations, schedule-change

for a [PLUS ticket on tap](https://www.flytap.com/en-us/booking-information/tap-products), which advertise "free changes", I cannot seem to get them.

On the website, there's a bug that won't allow me to change a single passenger. The confirmation screen shows all passengers and I ain't clicking agree on that. But even on the website, selecting a flight that is cheaper than the one I am holding will charge U$7.50. So not free.

Since I cannot make the change on the website, I tried the phone. It gets worse. They don't know about the website limitation/bug and to do the change there, again on flights cheaper than the one I am holding, there's a EU$36.70 fee.

So, Is there any way to hold them accountable for the "Free changes" advertisement?

Comment: You can ask them on social media (e.g. Twitter). Some airlines are very reactive to that, don’t know about TAP.  Don’t threaten anything but be negative, just ask. Otherwise it’s probably small claims court or the local equivalent m, but that will take some time (and you’ll need to have evidence).

Comment: Do you have anything in writing about the free changes?

Comment: what's a "TAP" in this context?

Comment: @njzk2 TAP is the portuguese flag carrier (airline).

Comment: @NicolasFormichella it is widely displayed on all their purchase/info pages. You see "free changes"/"no fee changes" all over the place.

Comment: @jcaron I don't think i held a twitter account since 2010.

Comment: Yes, but what is actually written in your fare rules is what counts, not the advertising

Comment: @NicolasFormichella these are the fare rules. The only other document airlines gives you are the eticket, which does not  mention any of that in any case, only from/to and price/tax/fees. even my polaris business etickets mention none of that. you have to match eticket "class" to the ones listed on the marketing site.

Answer (score 1):

Still not free, but a small workaround I found.

you can call them and ask to split the ticket, to get a new reservation code per passenger. This is free via the phone.

After you have one code per passenger, the broken website will not crash and you will be able to just be scammed out of some USD$8 per change.

Still far from free, but better than EU$36 per change.

Comment: In some cases (which is not necessarily true in your case), the changed ticket will need to remain in the same category as the original ticket (e.g. Flex or Plus or whatever) and the price is not the cheapest displayed price for e.g. basic economy.

Comment: makes sense. but it is undeniable it is a fee since: 1. all flights will show at least that extra cost, 2. even after selecting one of those, my eticket was updated to show a new *cheaper* flight in the cost description. So i did pick one that was cheaper than mine and still paid the fee.